# how to display user address instead of form fields in woocommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i want to add a condition to my theme that handle if a user has a address in their account show that address and send the order to that address and check out form fill with that address and if user doesnt have any saved address or not logged in or want to change the address display the form
for example
if user has address:
display the address ...

if user doesnt have address:
the form fileds

in my check out form i have :

```
<?php do_action('woocommerce_checkout_billing'); ?>

<?php do_action('woocommerce_checkout_shipping'); ?>
```

for addresses

i found this function but i dont know if it fills the checkout form or not?
iam new in wordpress and php so i appreciate your helps.